# Connecting an N - N Sharepoint Relation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, many-to-many

I'm currently developing a SharePoint site which I need to set up two many to many relationships.

List1 n <--> n List2 n <--> n List3

Keys for each list are: CID, RID, and PID.

I have an additional two lists which join the lists:
ListCID-RID
ListPID-RID

These two lists have two columns both of which are lookups.
ListCID-RID has a lookup column to List1: CID and List2: RID.
ListPID-RID has a lookup column to List2: RID and List3: PID.

With these relations if I manually add data and link it I can generate the appropriate views I need, however I'm having trouble with creating new items.

When a new item is created in List2 the RID is generated by getting a GUID.  List1 and List3 items can only be created when you are referring to List2.  Basically the RID is passed to the new form for List1/List3 and then the list generates its own GUID.

What I'm having trouble with is finding a way to link the lists.

The options I currently think I have are:

1. Hook the form submit button to create the item in ListCID-RID or ListPID-RID.  I've seen examples for URL redirecting and would use the same approach.
2. Have the form button submit to another aspx page which takes the RID and CID/PID and creates the list item and then redirects.  I'm concerned this method would be slow.
3. Use a workflow.  I'm trying to stay away from workflows.
4. Create an event receiver.  I don't know where to start with this one or if I'm even able to do it within my environment constraints.

Right now the issue I'm running in to is that ListCID-RID and ListPID-RID only contain lookups, which means that the items must exist in List1, List2 or List3 before they can be connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any who find this via search engines this is the method that I ended up with.

I created two linking lists (for five total):

- CID
- CID-RID
- RID
- PID
- PID-RID

The workflow is that when a new item is created it starts off in the RID list.  I create something in the RID list and through jquery I get a GUID for it.

Now if the user wants to create a CID or a PID I pass the GUID along and then create the new CID/PID.  These CID/PID each have their own GUIDs as well.

Once that new PID/CID is created I pass both GUIDs on to an interim page and programmatically I create an item in CID-RID or PID-RID.  The page then forwards the user back to the main view.

Due to issues with SharePoint I ended up passing values via browser local storage and as http parameters.

It's not an elegant solution and feels like more of a hack, but as of right now it's working decently.